# Where do files uploaded via Media Manager get stored in MU?

Tags: theme-development, multisite

Standard WordPress sites, at least of the versions of WP I've tested, store files uploaded via the Media Manager under wp-content/uploads/

Where do these same files get stored in MU sites and how can you obtain a reference to this folder via script from functions.php?

Is the location different depending on which version of WP or WPMU is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following page and see if that answers the question for you... ;)
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/ms-default-constants.php

Comment: /wp-content/blogs.dir/[siteid]/files/

Comment: Perhaps another question, but related: How to determine, from functions.php, if the site is WPMU or standard? And how to get siteid via script? {$wpdb->blogid} ?

Comment: See Andrea's answer, and i think she's referring to `wp_upload_dir()` if i'm following correctly... :)

Answer (score 2):

Do a check for is_site_admin - if it's true, the network is enabled.

If you use the usual WP uploads folder function call, it will magically find the multisite ones as well. (I can't remember it off the top of my head)